# It is possible to control which file should load for class in ClassLoader

Tags: java, classloader

I am working on a project needs to dynamic load modules(which are jars with dependency jars). My attempt is to generate a ClassLoader and use app ClassLoader as parent for each module to make objects castable with two ClassLoaders(app and module). But some module have the same dependencies as the main app with different version cause some exception like 'FieldNotFound'. Is there any way to control which .class or .jar file should load by ClassLoader for each classes?

I have tried OSGi, but it's too complex for me to handle it. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20330490/bnd-importing-optional-requirements-and-cannot-exclude

Comment: @RomanVottner but separate ClassLoaders will make class uncastable between ClassLoader, how to solve that? In my case it's not as simple as cloning, they should be able to communicate with each other.

Comment: @RomanVottner Or is there any way to override the mechanism to control  ClassLoader load dependencies from files?